# The point probability of a random variable

Tags: probability

I'm trying to understand the following integral:

$\begin{align*}
\mathcal P(draw \mid \boldsymbol \mu, \boldsymbol \Sigma) 
&= 
\lim_{{ \epsilon}\rightarrow 0}
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z
\\&= 
\mathcal N \left(
0;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) 
\end{align*}$

Which appears in J. Moser, “[The Math Behind TrueSkill](http://www.moserware.com/assets/computing-your-skill/The%20Math%20Behind%20TrueSkill.pdf)”.

To clarify, this is the integration of a multivariate Gaussian distribution. The vector $\mathbf z$ between the bounds $-\epsilon\mathbf 1$ and $-\epsilon\mathbf 1$, where $\mathbf 1$ is just a vector of same dimension as $\mathbf z$ filled with $1$ meaning the elements of $\mathbf z$ individually all are bounded from $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$.

Clearly the normal distribution is being written as $\mathcal N(variable; mean, variance)$ which is more commonly in my experience seen as $\mathcal N(variable \mid mean, variance)$.

This integral of course is of a Normal PDF, and thus is the CDF, or calculating the probability that all the elements of $\mathbf z$ fall between $-\epsilon$ and $\epsilon$. I'm good with that. We could of course also be tempted to write this integral as:

$\Phi\left(
\mathbf \epsilon\mathbf 1;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) -
\Phi\left(
\mathbf -\epsilon\mathbf 1;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right)$

If we lean on fairly ordinary CDF notation, but would be mistaken as is clearly spelled out for the 2D case here:

http://orfe.princeton.edu/~rvdb/245/Fall14/lectures/chap3.pdf

The details of the mean and variance aren't immediately relevant to my question (I understand what they all are, whence they stem and what they mean).

The problem I am grappling with is how to understand the limit. As $\epsilon$ tends to $0$ I expect the integral too to diminish to zero, as the $\mathcal P(-\epsilon)$ and $\mathcal P(\epsilon)$ converge toward the same value of $\mathcal P(0)$

But the stated result is not $0$, it is $\mathcal P(0)$.

I'm confused on two fronts I think. Firstly how it is that this limit does not yield $0$, but secondly how the integral (a CDF) becomes a point probability (PDF).

And lastly I guess, central to my confusion is how $\mathcal P(x)$ is not equal to $0$ for any given x for a continuous random variable. It translates to the probability of getting exactly one specific value in the real number space and one might intuit that to be effectively $0$.

To wit, I conclude that there is something I am not understanding about the interpretation of a PDF and the probability of a given point in the real number space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first quoted equation is certainly wrong -- that limit is zero, as you expected. However, apparently the source article actually uses the following "normalized match quality":

$$\begin{align} 
q_{\text draw}(\mathbf{ \mu,\Sigma,\beta,A}):&=\lim_{{ \epsilon}\rightarrow 0}{
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z
\over
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf 0,
\mathbf  \beta^2 \mathbf A^\intercal\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z
}\tag{1a}\\[2ex]
&=\lim_{{ \epsilon}\rightarrow 0}{{1\over (2\epsilon)^d}
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z
\over {1\over (2\epsilon)^d}
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf 0,
\mathbf  \beta^2 \mathbf A^\intercal\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z
}\tag{1b}\\[2ex]
&={\lim_{{ \epsilon}\rightarrow 0}{1\over (2\epsilon)^d}
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z
\over \lim_{{ \epsilon}\rightarrow 0}{1\over (2\epsilon)^d}
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf 0,
\mathbf  \beta^2 \mathbf A^\intercal\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z
}\tag{1c}\\[2ex]
&={
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf 0;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) 
\over
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf 0;
\mathbf 0,
\mathbf  \beta^2 \mathbf A^\intercal\mathbf A
\right)\tag{1d}
}\end{align}
$$
where $\mathcal N$ is the PDF of a $d$-dimensional multivariate Normal distribution.

Note that (1c) is because the limit of a ratio is the ratio of limits (the denominator being nonzero), and (1d) is a consequence of the **Mean Value Theorem for Multiple Integrals**, one version of which is as follows (see $^*$ below for links to proofs):

> If $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ is a *continuous Riemann integrable* function on a *connected Jordan measurable* set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^d$, then there exists $\mathbf z_0\in S$ such that $$\int_{S}f\mathbf{\,dz}=f(\mathbf{z_0})\,\int_{S}\mathbf{\,dz} $$

This applies to the numerators of (1), for example, with $f(\mathbf{z})=\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf{z}\ ;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right),$ and with $S=S_\epsilon$ (now depending on $\epsilon$) a $d$-dimensional cube of edge-length $2\epsilon$ centered on the origin $\mathbf{0}$. For all $\epsilon>0$ as $\epsilon\to 0,$ the theorem ensures that there exists a $\mathbf z_\epsilon\in S_\epsilon$ such that
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z
&= 
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z_\epsilon;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right)\,\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1} d\mathbf z
\\[2ex] &= 
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z_\epsilon;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right)\,(2\epsilon)^d .\end{align}$$
Then, since $S_\epsilon\to\{\mathbf{0}\}$ (and hence $\mathbf z_\epsilon\to\mathbf 0$) as $\epsilon\to 0,$
$$\lim_{{ \epsilon}\rightarrow 0}{1\over (2\epsilon)^d}
\int_{-\epsilon \mathbf 1}^{\epsilon \mathbf 1}
\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) d\mathbf z\\ =\lim_{{ \epsilon}\rightarrow 0}{1\over (2\epsilon)^d}\ \mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z_\epsilon;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right)\,(2\epsilon)^d\\
=\lim_{{ \epsilon}\rightarrow 0} \mathcal N \left(
\mathbf z_\epsilon;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right)\\
=\mathcal N \left(
\mathbf 0;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right) $$
and similarly for the denominators in (1).

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+integrate(+PDF%5BNormalDistribution%5B%5Cmu,%5Csigma%5D,z%5D,+z%3D-%5Cepsilon..%5Cepsilon)%2F(2%5Cepsilon),+%5Cepsilon+-%3E+0)'s a Wolfram Alpha link for the one-dimensional version.

---

$^*$ Here are some links to proofs of various versions of the theorem (I used Apostol's):

[Mathematical Analysis](https://www.scribd.com/document/8142904/Mathematical-Analysis-Apostol) (Apostol, Theorem 14.16, p.401)

[Is there a mean-value theorem for volume integrals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2021804/is-there-a-mean-value-theorem-for-volume-integrals)

[The Mean Value Theorem for Multiple Integrals](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2009/12/29/the-mean-value-theorem-for-multiple-integrals/)

---

**NB**: The following is too long for a comment: You wrote ...

> We could of course also write this integral as:$$\Phi\left(
> \mathbf \epsilon\mathbf 1;
> \mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
> \mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
> \right) -
> \Phi\left(
> \mathbf -\epsilon\mathbf 1;
> \mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
> \mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
> \right)$$ If we lean on fairly ordinary CDF notation.

To see that's not correct, see [here](http://orfe.princeton.edu/~rvdb/245/Fall14/lectures/chap3.pdf) for a nice graphical demonstration in the two-dimensional case. E.g., if we have $\mathbf{z}=(z_1,z_2)$, and define

$$F(z_1,z_2):=\Phi\left(
\mathbf z;
\mathbf A^\intercal\boldsymbol \mu,
\mathbf A^\intercal (\beta^2\mathbf I+\boldsymbol \Sigma)\mathbf A
\right)$$
 then the probability of the square $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is *not* generally $F(\epsilon,\epsilon)-F(-\epsilon,-\epsilon)$, but rather $$F(\epsilon,\epsilon)+F(-\epsilon,-\epsilon)-F(-\epsilon,\epsilon)-F(\epsilon,-\epsilon).$$

Comment: Lovely. Can you explain where the $\frac {1} {2\epsilon}$ comes from? I can see that it helps to make the limit non trivial (as in the numerator and denominator both tend to 0 and hence depending on the rates this can limit to a nonj zero value of course) but I can't see where it comes from.

Comment: @BerndWechner - That should've been ${1\over(2\epsilon)^d}.$ I've added a geometric explanation.

Comment: Area under $f(x)$ between $a$ and $b$ is calculated as:

$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$

that is the two dimensions of the area are in fact, height defined the function and breadth defined by the $x$ or better said $x$ between $a$ and $b$.

And so the integral provides area, and by inference a multivariate integral a volume, without such a scaling factor. So I’m struggling to see how this factor contributes to the volume … much rather it seems to be normalizing the volume, such that the resulting limit can indeed rightly be expected to be an average of $f(x)$ over the span $a$ to $b$.

Comment: Still, in the limit (as $a$ tends to $b$), I am tempted to suspect that the notion of “average of $f(x)$ over the span $a$ to $b$” and “area under $f(x)$ over the span $a$ to $b$” collapse to the same value and idea. If so of course I would love to find something in the literature to cite in that regard, or find a good proof. I of course am musing and speculating.

Comment: The Wolfram Alpha thing rocks BTW. I'm reading up on improper integrals now and limits of integrals but not homing in on anything that talks through the limit as the integration limits converge (toward a single point). It's not made easier by the fact that the terms "limits" and "integration limits" overlap.

Comment: Found it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function. So indeed you are suggesting the original author wanted to calculate $q_draw$ a ratio of averages not as a ratio of probabilities (areas) and thus a small error crept into their definition of the numerator as $\mathcal P(draw)$, both omitting the $\frac{1}{b-a}$ and falsely describing it as a probability ($\mathcal P$). I think it would more rightly be descried as a PDF mean ($\overline{\mathcal N}$). Is there a better term?

Comment: @BerndWechner -  Maybe this will help ... Suppose $F$ is an everywhere continous CDF (e.g. Normal), and let $f=F'$ be the corresponding PDF. Then, by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Formal_statement), for any $a<b$, there is a $c\in(a,b)$ such that  ${F(b)-F(a)\over b-a}=f(c).$ Hence, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $c\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ such that ${F(\epsilon)-F(-\epsilon)\over 2\epsilon}=f(c).$ Therefore, $\lim_\limits{\epsilon\to 0} {F(\epsilon)-F(-\epsilon)\over 2\epsilon}=f(0).$

Comment: And I suspect it is also axiomatic that if $\overline{f(x)}\mid_a^b=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$, that $\lim_{a\rightarrow b} \overline{f(x)}\mid_a^b = f(b)$.

Comment: @BerndWechner - Yes, by the mean value theorem.

Comment: I'm now pursuing a proof, that the second line in your intro follows from the first. Playing around with L'Hopital's rule, but no success yet. I wonder, do you have a proof that you can add to the answer? I guess similar follows for the two limit solutions you posted, am curious on proof. To be honest, just driven by curiosity now.

Comment: Thanks for the update on the erroneous $\Phi$ representation. I updated the question with the same comment basically. I remain curious on a proof as noted in previous comment.